# Is is possible to send a link via email or text to an Android device that will open your own custom app with contained parameters?

Tags: android

I can't really add much more to the title. I want to send out alerts to users with links that open up my app directly.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from working with Google Adwords that it is indeed possible to send users to a specific deep link location in you app. As an example of sending a user to a specific product page, you would use a URL such as `android-app://com.example.android/exampleapp/productid_1234`

Read more - https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6046977?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this simply by adding intent to send your data.
i am sharing a code sample just implement it and you will get what you want:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
        // what to do with it.


        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER_NAME,"example");
        // share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your text");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "click on com.example.yourApp");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, ""));
```

Just place `your app complete name with package name` on place of `com.example.yourApp`